# How to get URL in http.Request

Tags: go

I built an HTTP server. I am using the code below to get the request URL, but it does not get full URL.

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {  
    fmt.Printf("Req: %s %s", r.URL.Host, r.URL.Path)
}
```

I only get `"Req:  / "` and `"Req: /favicon.ico"`.

I want to get full client request URL as `"1.2.3.4/"` or `"1.2.3.4/favicon.ico"`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From the documentation of net/http package:

```
type Request struct {
   ...
   // The host on which the URL is sought.
   // Per RFC 2616, this is either the value of the Host: header
   // or the host name given in the URL itself.
   // It may be of the form "host:port".
   Host string
   ...
}
```

Modified version of your code:

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("Req: %s %s\n", r.Host, r.URL.Path) 
}
```

Example output:

```
Req: localhost:8888 /
```

Comment: Can NOT believe that an Http Request doesn't keep the whole Url/Uri as a string somewhere. Seems REALLY silly to me. (:facepalm:)

Answer (score 19):

I use `req.URL.RequestURI()` to get the full url.

From `net/http/requests.go` :

```
// RequestURI is the unmodified Request-URI of the
// Request-Line (RFC 2616, Section 5.1) as sent by the client
// to a server. Usually the URL field should be used instead.
// It is an error to set this field in an HTTP client request.
RequestURI string
```

Answer (score 9):

If you detect that you are dealing with a relative URL (`r.URL.IsAbs() == false`), you sill have access to `r.Host` ([see `http.Request`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request)), the `Host` itself.

Concatenating the two would give you the full URL.

Generally, you see the reverse (extracting Host from an URL), as in [`gorilla/reverse/matchers.go`](https://github.com/gorilla/reverse/blob/master/matchers.go#L238-L249)

```
// getHost tries its best to return the request host.
func getHost(r *http.Request) string {
    if r.URL.IsAbs() {
        host := r.Host
        // Slice off any port information.
        if i := strings.Index(host, ":"); i != -1 {
            host = host[:i]
        }
        return host
    }
    return r.URL.Host
}
```

Comment: I was baffled by this until I saw your check with relative URL, good catch! I have a relative URL and following your guide, I can get the host now, but I also need the scheme, do you know how to get it?

Comment: @nullgraph not sure right now: you could make that a question on its own.