# Get full URL in WebSocket

Tags: go

I'm using one of the golang [samples](https://github.com/golang-samples/websocket) to build a WebSocket server. According to the samples the struct `Client` access `websocket.Conn` [here](https://github.com/golang-samples/websocket/blob/master/websocket-chat/src/chat/client.go#L42) and `websocket.Conn` has a `Request` method returning `*http.Request`.

My idea is to subscribe the user to different channels depending on the subdomain they use to enter the app.

So is it possible to get the full URL the user hit when subscribed to the websocket? Using the sample code I thought `ws.Conn.Request().URL.Host` would give me something like `ws://channel1.lvh.me:8080/sync` but instead I'm getting the path: "/chat".

Is it possible to get the full URL the user used to connect to the websocket? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [How to get URL in http.Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151827/how-to-get-url-in-http-request), also: [Why are request.URL.Host and Scheme blank in the development server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899069/why-are-request-url-host-and-scheme-blank-in-the-development-server) Also useful: [Is the full, absolute URL of an HTTP request directly available?](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/144j758twr/go-nuts-is-the-full-absolute-url-of-an-http-request-directly-available)

Answer (score 1):

Examine the [host header](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Host) to get the requested host:

```
host := c.Request().Host
```

The [Request.URL](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.URL) field is parsed from the HTTP request URI. For most requests, the request URI contains path and query only.

An application can reconstruct a full URL from the host header and knowledge of the protocols the application is serving.  For example, if the application is listening for HTTP requests (or WS request that use HTTP for handshake), the full URL is:

```
u := *c.Request().URL
u.Host = c.Request().Host
u.Scheme = "http"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`func (*Conn) Request`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket#Conn.Request) returns `*http.Request`

```
func (ws *Conn) Request() *http.Request
```

Checking the [`http.Request`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request) from the `http` package you will observe that it has a `URL *url.URL` type. This means that you should get the full url with:

```
ws.Request().URL.Path
```